# iPad: How can I implement a scrolling timeline using a static image?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I'm diving into iOS development and I'm building a simple timeline app using a static timeline image that I already have. The timeline image won't fit on the screen. The width of the image is about five times the width of the iPad screen, so I have to allow the user to scroll the image horizontally. Here's a mockup...

[image]

For each item on the timeline, the user can tap it to receive a description at the bottom of the screen.  My questions are...

1. I was planning to use a UIScrollView with a PageControl at the bottom. Can a UIScrollView hold a single view that holds the entire timeline image or do I have to break the the timeline image up into multiple views?
2. Are there any performance issues I need to consider when implementing this with a UIScrollView, using a static image?
3. Are there other approaches to implementing this scrollable timeline that I should consider other than using a UIScrollView?

Thanks so much in advance for your wisdom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you'll need a UIScrollView. However, you could use a CATiledLayer to make it perform well. You would just need to pre-tile your static image. Try out the [ShutterStock app in the app store](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/shutterstock-for-ipad/id473347409?mt=8) (it's free). They have a really nicely done horizontal scrolling implementation that I believe uses a CATiledLayer (though I'm not completely sure).

I did a tutorial on using the CATiledLayer a while back. You can check it out here: http://www.cimgf.com/2011/03/01/subduing-catiledlayer/

If you are going to support iOS 6 and up only, you could look into using a UICollectionView which is very efficient. It works similarly to a UITableView with the cell re-use pattern, but allows you to have horizontal scrolling like you're looking for.